# Netty IdleStateHandler network and cpu prioriy

Tags: netty

I am using nettys IdleStateHandler and when server or network is busy my clients disconnect. is it possible to set a higher priority ( network and cpu ) for heartbeat messages ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.  TCP is a stream-oriented protocol.  Even if you send a heart-beat message as early as possible, the server will not see it when it is is too busy handling the messages arrived previously.